# Reclass If/then logic

Tags: raster, reclassify, conditional

Have a binary raster. I would like to remove any 'islands' that are fully surrounded by one of the classes while leaving the 'islands' that are fully surrounded by the other.

If 1 is enveloped by 0, then reclassify to 0. If 0 is enveloped by 1, leave as one.

Essentially a select by location, but for raster.
This is super easy in vector - struggling to find a solution in raster.  Am I overlooking the obvious?

Platforms of choice are Arc or QGIS.

Comment: Could you specify which tools you use?

Comment: What particular GIS software do you wish to ask about?

Comment: Arc, QGIS, Imagine

Comment: Raster to polygon, fix (you say this is super easy in vector), then polygon to raster.

Comment: Or you can get away with a combination of raster calculator in Arc toolbox. the following string will get rid of the lonely '1' values. .
Con((FocalStatistics("%test.tif%",NbrRectangle(3,3,"CELL"),"SUM")==1) & ("%test.tif%"==1),0,"%test.tif%")

To get rid of the 0 values:
Con((FocalStatistics("%test.tif%",NbrRectangle(3,3,"CELL"),"SUM")==8) & ("%test.tif%"==0),1,"%test.tif%")

Comment: The same can be done in Qgis by using a r.neighbours (grass) followed by a raster calculator.

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question.  You can always ask about the other one in a separate question.  Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our site and its protocols.